# Android JNI development fails to build - convert-dependencies.sh

Tags: android, build, java-native-interface

I've had to port an android JNI development (not working yet) to another machine. On the original machine it compiled and linked OK.

But on the new machine I get a build error

---

Compile thumb  : main <= main.c

./obj/convert-dependencies.sh: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file

make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/main/main.o] Error 2

make: *** Deleting file `obj/local/armeabi/objs/main/main.o'

### /cygdrive/c/Android/android-ndk-r7c/build/core/build-binary.mk:240: recipe for target `obj/local/armeabi/objs/main/main.o' failed

Maybe it's an environment problem - any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

convert-dependencies.sh is a sed file containing the line

## AUTO-GENERATED FILE, DO NOT EDIT!

It seems that the file is environment dependent - it converts references to windows style root directories (c:\ , d:\ ...) to unix style (/cygdrive/c ...) AND it is not removed or rebuilt  on a project clean or build.

So the old version from  the old machine remained and contained references to non-existent drives which seems to cause it to malfunction. When I deleted this file and did a rebuild it correctly rebuilt the offending file and correctly built the project